# Trying to install hadoop on a Linux system, getting error while editing .bashrc file

Tags: bash, hadoop

I am installing hadoop in my system while trying to make permanent .bashrc changes using --source ~/.bashrc getting the error below:

```
/home/tcs/hadoop>source ~/.bashrc
ksh: .[5]: .[35]: shopt: not found [No such file or directory]
ksh: .[5]: .[46]: shopt: not found [No such file or directory]
ksh: .[5]: .[65]: [: argument expected
```

the .bashrc file content is

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions


export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/home/tcs/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
```

Comment: I think you are running `source` from your current shell which is a `ksh` shell. So obviously bash commands are not recognized in it. Can you do `echo $SHELL` before sourcing the `.bashrc` file?

Comment: @lnian tried your solution but still getting the same error--   terminal--/home/tcs>echo $SHELL
/bin/ksh
/home/tcs>source ~/.bashrc
ksh: .[5]: .[35]: shopt: not found [No such file or directory]
ksh: .[5]: .[46]: shopt: not found [No such file or directory]
ksh: .[5]: .[65]: [: argument expected
/home/tcs>

Comment: I didn't say what did will solve your problem. Just to check which shell you were running. It is `/bin/ksh`. you can't run `.bashrc` from it. First lauch a bash interactive prompt by doing `bash` on the command line

Comment: thanks @lnian it works

Answer (score 0):

There should be a respective rc file for ksh that you need to edit instead.

And if you find it, note that bash and ksh have slightly different syntaxes, but that shouldn't be an issue if you are only exporting environment variables

Also, latest versions of Hadoop do not support Java 6, so you'll need to update the Java home variable

Answer (score 0):

It seems you run ksh (Korn-shell) environment. According to the [.kshrc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.files/kshrc.htm):

> The $HOME/.kshrc file is a shell script that customizes the Korn-shell
> environment. This .kshrc script often contains a list of environment
> variables, command aliases, and function definitions that customize
> the Korn-shell environment.

You can add your `EXPORT` statements to the .kshrc file as they are. The issue you see is with the script located in the `/etc/bashrc` file.

Or as an alternative, use `bash` instead. Simply run `/bin/bash` for a one time use. Or set it up as a default shell via `chsh -s /bin/bash`. You must log out and log back in to see this change.